# Cannot execute same CSS Path in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I'm using casperjs for do some web scraping.
This is the problem, I need to get value from datepicker and then pick one date by this css path code :

```
#datepicker_div > div.datepicker_oneMonth.datepicker_newRow > table > tbody > tr:nth-child("+2+") > td:nth-child("+6+")"
```

and I get the value with this code

```
var t = $("#datepicker_div > div.datepicker_oneMonth.datepicker_newRow > table > tbody > tr:nth-child("+2+") > td:nth-child("+6+")").text();
```

I put that code in this.evaluate() function.

So I came with another needs, which is clicking the date from my prefered position (2,6)
Then I do some code like this

```
var arrival = $("#datepicker_div > div.datepicker_oneMonth.datepicker_newRow > table > tbody > tr:nth-child("+2+") > td:nth-child("+6+") > a");
arrival.click();
```

and then, my code was timed out, and the date was not set properly...what I supposed to do, is there something that I missed?

Comment: Why don't you use CasperJS' native functions to do this like `casper.fetchText` and `casper.click`. If you use those, you will get better error messages.

Comment: If you use PhantomJS, you need to know that sometimes `:nth-child` selectors don't work correctly. In that case you can use XPath.

Comment: Because I need to get and click text from the datepicker when popping out...Is it possible to get the date element and click them with casper default function?

Comment: It seems that you can use the CasperJS functions judging from those little code snippets. Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: WOW...It works...thanks Artjom B :D